# Automatic spacing adjust in Python

Tags: python, spacing

I have a Python code with a mixture of 2 and 4 spacing. I would like to make it consistent. Is there any software that can automatically do it? Ideally, it can adjust for a given range of lines, e.g., 1-300. So I can test the adjustment segment by segment.

Comment: Requesting software/tools is specifically off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. perhaps I should go https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/